Reactsj div doesn't center in various browsers
I'm finding trouble in centering a div in my react app.
The jsx code:
function Loading() {
    return (
        <div class="loader">
            <h1>Hello World</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Loading

CSS (inside public/index.html):
    .loader {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }

I have TailwindCSS and DaisyUI installed. I tried adding width: 100%; to loader class but that didn't work either. I faced this issue initially on chromium, then I found the same issue on chrome and firefox. The os is Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. Unlike the image, I want the content to be in center of the screen, and not stick to the top:

Thank You!

Using text-align: center didn't work either

To center the .loader div in the middle of the screen, you need to ensure that its parent container covers the entire viewport height. Here's how you can achieve that:
import React from 'react';

function Loading() {
    return (
        <div className="flex items-center justify-center h-screen">
            <div className="loader">
                <h1>Hello World</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Loading;
Please let me know if this not working for you.

Hey! Thanks for the help but the issue is still not resolved.The output is still the same as in the image I'd attached before. Update: adding style={{height: "100vh"}} to the parent container fixed the issue.
